# rangeslider.js mousedown event not working on slider button

Tags: javascript, jquery, rangeslider

Mouse event is not firing.
Need to know the hold event so can disable the update of slider value.
my code is,

```
var sliding = false;
function update_seek_value(value){
  if(!sliding){
            $("#replay-slider").val(value).change();
  }
}
$('.slider_button_class_name').on('mousedown',function(){
   sliding = true;
});
```

Comment: $(".slider_button_class_name").on("input change", function() { doSomething(); }); with jQuery is alternative of this answer.

Comment: This  doesn't work. in your case event is being attached to a visible input type range. mousedown event is easily attached  too on it.
I'm using it with rangeslider.js  and this slider button which is a div doesn't attach mousedown event to it.
url : http://rangeslider.js.org/

Comment: check answer updated!!! as per your requirement

Comment: mousedown event is, mouse left key is pressed i have worked with all the functions mentioned in  rangeslider.js.org.Nothing is related to mousedown. Even if u add a mousedown event  to slider-button div that is $(".rangeslider__handle").mousedown(function(){
//do something .
});
it doesn't work.

Comment: I glad you do your own way :-) but if you explain me  my answer is not working? than i will give your answer up vote

Comment: onSlideEnd is a custom event, it's not at all similar to 'oninput' and 'onchange' event for sure. i update my slide bar with continuous ajax request that lets user know that document media is moving forward and user can use the slide button to see the document media  from anywhere.so i cannot use this two events. onSlideEnd is a event that defines that user has completed sliding  and gives position and  value. it's 
 a complete event of startevent :[mousedown,touchstart], moveEvent: ["mousemove", "touchmove", "pointermove"]
endEvent:[mouseup,touchend]

Comment: ok!!!! good :-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#range-control").rangeslider({
    polyfill: false,
    onSlideEnd: function(position, value){
        //console.log('Position', position, 'Value', value);
        $("#selectedRange").text(value);
    }
});
```

```css
body, input[type=text] { text-align: center; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/1.2.1/rangeslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/1.2.1/rangeslider.min.js"></script>
<input id="range-control" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
<span id="selectedRange"></span>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the assistance on this anyway i found the solution on my own.Hope this  will help someone who is  stuck to similar kind of problem.
Solution was to override the js 'rangeslider.min.js'

As of my knowledge one can disable the 'events' either by using $('selector').off("mousedown") or stoping the event propogation.
i was using '/yourlocalpath/rangeslider.js' mentioned in rangeslider.js.org
there is a javascript event that is stoping the propogation event for events like mousedown and touchstart,but basically it is listening to mousdown event so i updated my flag just above the code of stop event popogation.
The code in rangeslider.js where i added my flag.

```
j.prototype.handleDown = function(a) {
console.log("mousedown event triggered"); // TRY TO FIND THIS LINE IN YOUR DOWNLOADED JS OF RANGESLIDER
sliding = true;                           // ADD YOUR MOUSEDOWN EVENTS HERE
if (a.preventDefault(), this.$document.on(this.moveEvent, this.handleMove), this.$document.on(this.endEvent, this.handleEnd), !((" " + a.target.className + " ").replace(/[\n\t]/g, " ").indexOf(this.options.handleClass) > -1)) {
  var b = this.getRelativePosition(a),
    c = this.$range[0].getBoundingClientRect()[this.DIRECTION],
    d = this.getPositionFromNode(this.$handle[0]) - c,
    e = "vertical" === this.orientation ? this.maxHandlePos - (b - this.grabPos) : b - this.grabPos;
  this.setPosition(e), b >= d && b < d + this.handleDimension && (this.grabPos = b - d)
}
}
```